# Why is there still a lack of Bitmain chips for miners?

Tags: asic, cgminer, antminer

All of the ASIC miner producers still claim that there are not enough chips for miners to produce anything.

But if China is allegedly fully back to normal and has been for some time, why is there still a lack of Bitmain ASICs for miners?

Answer (score 0):

According to a [Bloomberg article](https://www.bloomberg.com/graphics/2021-semiconductors-chips-shortage/)

> That explosion in demand—unexpectedly goosed during the Covid-19 pandemic for certain industries like smartphones and PCs—has caused a near-term supply shock triggering an unprecedented global shortage.

...

> The crunch has sideswiped the General Motors and Volkswagens of the world and swung politicians from Washington to Beijing into crisis control. It’s also catapulted Taiwan Semiconductor Manufacturing Co. and Samsung Electronics Co. to the top of investor and government agendas. Asia’s two largest chipmakers are responsible for making the vast majority of the world’s most advanced silicon, yet don’t have the capacity to sate all demand. It’s a bottleneck that could last several quarters—or into next year.

So there is unprecedented global demand on chip fabs. Those businesses are doubtless prioritizing their largest customers and their biggest selling products. ICs used by relatively low volume manufacturers like Bitmain might be a long way down on the list.

Comment: I just knew this just in time manufacturing wasn't going to work out.